# MySQL Query - Mixture of sorting and grouping

Tags: mysql, sql, sorting, grouping

I'am trying to get the following information from a table:

- sorting by "b" (table A ascending, table B descending)
- all "u" with a particular value appears first (in this example u=3) - then the order is not important
- N (NULL) always at the end
- no "r" may occur twice (but all different "r" must be present)

With "ORDER BY IFNULL(u, 99999999) != 3 , u , b" criterion 1, 2 and 3 works, but for the last, I have no clue.

With DISTINCT I don't reach the target, just as with GROUP BY.

Does anyone have an idea?
Many thanks in advance.

```
start table          target table A 
+----------------+   +----------------+
| id | r | u | b |   | id | r | u | b |
+----------------+   +----------------+
|  1 | 1 | 1 | 9 |   | 18 | 5 | 3 | 1 |
|  2 | 1 | 3 | 4 |   | 2  | 1 | 3 | 4 |
|  3 | 1 | 4 | 6 |   | 15 | 4 | 3 | 7 |
|  4 | 1 | 5 | 5 |   | 11 | 3 | 3 | 8 |
|  5 | 2 | 1 | 2 |   | *  | 2 | * | * |
|  6 | 2 | 2 | 1 |   | 21 | 6 | N | N |
|  7 | 2 | 4 | 5 |   +----------------+
|  8 | 2 | 5 | 7 |
|  9 | 3 | 1 | 4 |
| 10 | 3 | 2 | 3 |
| 11 | 3 | 3 | 8 |
| 12 | 3 | 5 | 2 |   target table B
| 13 | 4 | 1 | 3 |   +----------------+
| 14 | 4 | 2 | 2 |   | id | r | u | b |
| 15 | 4 | 3 | 7 |   +----------------+
| 16 | 4 | 4 | 6 |   | 11 | 3 | 3 | 8 |
| 17 | 5 | 2 | 9 |   | 15 | 4 | 3 | 7 |
| 18 | 5 | 3 | 1 |   | 2  | 1 | 3 | 4 |
| 19 | 5 | 4 | 6 |   | 18 | 5 | 3 | 1 |
| 20 | 5 | 5 | 4 |   | *  | 2 | * | * |
| 21 | 6 | N | N |   | 21 | 6 | N | N |
+----------------+   +----------------+
```

Comment: How do you choose  which rows to take when there are more then 2 values on the `R` column? And I'm not sure I understood you, is `targetA` and `targetB` the output of `StartTable` ?

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: start table is the table in the db and target tables are my desired results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    mytable m
WHERE   id =
        (
        SELECT  id
        FROM    mytable mi
        WHERE   mi.r = m.r
        ORDER BY
                u IS NULL, u = 3 DESC, b, id
        LIMIT 1
        )
ORDER BY
        u IS NULL, u = 3 DESC, b
```

Update:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    objects o
LEFT JOIN
        ratings r
ON      r.id = COALESCE(
        (
        SELECT  id
        FROM    ratings
        WHERE   object_id = o.id
                AND user_id = :myuser
        ORDER BY
                rating DESC
        LIMIT   1
        ),
        (
        SELECT  id
        FROM    ratings
        WHERE   object_id = o.id
        ORDER BY
                rating DESC
        LIMIT   1
        )
        )
```

Comment: Has this construction a special name? I wish to understand this, but I can't!

Comment: @Seamanx: correlated subquery, I believe. In all other major systems you would just have used `ROW_NUMBER`, the window function, but MySQL does not support it.

Comment: If my table "mytable" is a left joined table (A LEFT JOIN B ON A.id = B.r) how can this correlated subquery work?
I think, I can't give the joined table an alias to work with.

Comment: @Seamanx: answering your direct question, yes, you can: `SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM a LEFT JOIN b ON a.id = b.r) q`. But from the looks of it, your whole setup is not the most efficient approach to the actual problem you're trying to solve. If you posted your problem in more detail, there's a chance we could have suggested a better solution.

Comment: I have a table A where objects listed (with properties) and in Table B where user (u) listed who rated (b) a object (r). The destination is, to show a list of all objects (each only once) sorted by the ranking of one user.

The ranking of all users was easier for me:

SELECT *, avg( B.b ) AS bb FROM A LEFT JOIN B ON A.id = B.r GROUP BY A.id ORDER BY bb

Comment: @seamanx: how large are your tables and how fast you need the query to be? The most efficient approach would be materializing your query, that is create a table which would store the highest ranking for each object and update it in a trigger whenever a ranking is added, deleted or modified. But again, it might not be worth the effort if your tables are not that large

Comment: @ Quassnoi: The size isn't a big deal: At the moment <100 in future: <1000. With my left joined table this correlated subquery doesn't work anymore, cause the id isn't unique anymore.
  This is my query: `SELECT  *
FROM    (SELECT a.id, u, b FROM a LEFT JOIN b ON a.id = b.r) m
WHERE   id =
        (
        SELECT  id
        FROM    (SELECT a.id, u, b FROM a LEFT JOIN b ON a.id = b.r) mi
        WHERE   mi.id = m.id
        ORDER BY
                u IS NULL, u = 3 DESC, b, id
        LIMIT 1
        )` any idea?

Comment: @Seamanx: so you want a list of all objects, along with the highest ranking from user 3 if any, or any other user, if any, or NULL if none, right?

Comment: @ Quassnoi: Right!

Comment: Now, I have a solution with `LEFT JOIN` (to connect 'a' and 'b' table) and `UNION` (to connect two queries (1: select users voting; 2: select the remain with `WHERE NOT IN`) constructions. Of course not the best solution, but it works ;-) Many thanks for giving ideas and introducing correlated subqueries!